# Runtime exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on executing Stored Proc

Tags: java

I am getting the below error when I try to execute a stored proc in Pointbase from weblogic.

```
java.sql.SQLException: The external "DbLog::insLog" routine had the following runtime exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DbLog"
```

So I setted the classpath in commEnv.cmd as follows,

```
set POINTBASE_HOME=%WL_HOME%\common\eval\pointbase 
set POINTBASE_CLIENT_CLASSPATH=%POINTBASE_HOME%\lib\pbclient57.jar 
set POINTBASE_CLASSPATH=%POINTBASE_HOME%\lib\pbembedded57.jar;%POINTBASE_CLIENT_CLASSPATH%;C:\bea\user_projects\workspaces\work1\utility\build\classes 
set POINTBASE_TOOLS=%POINTBASE_HOME%\lib\pbtools57.jar
```

My DbLog class is in the path, C:\bea\user_projects\workspaces\Work1\util\build\classes\net\local\util\common FYI, net\local\util\common is the package structure.

But when I try to execute the page which calls RequestFilter.java, I am getting the following error,

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.local.util.common.DbLog
```

--RequestFilter.java

```
  import net.local.util.common.DbLog;   

    public final class RequestFilter {   

    public void log() {   

    DbLog dblog = new DbLog();   
    dblog.logPreAuth();   
    }   
    }
```

--DbLog.java

```
  package net.local.util.common;   

    import java.sql.*;   
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;   
    import com.pointbase.jdbc.*;   


    public class DbLog {   


        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DbLog.class);   
        private static boolean DEBUGGING = logger.isDebugEnabled();   
        private Connection conn = null;   
        private Statement m_stmt;   
        private Statement l_stmt;   
        private CallableStatement m_callStmt = null;   
        //static ResultSet l_rs = null;

 public DbLog() {   

        logger.info("DbLog constructor called");   
        init();   

    }   

    public void init() {   
        logger.info("DbLog init called");   
    }   




    public void logPreAuth() {   

            try {   
                logger.info("Inside logPreAuth method");   



                String I_URL = "jdbc:pointbase:server://localhost:9093/weblogic_eval";   
                Class.forName("com.pointbase.jdbc.jdbcUniversalDriver").newInstance();   
                //Class.forName("com.pointbase.jdbc.jdbcDataSource");   
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(I_URL, "PBPUBLIC", "PBPUBLIC");   

            String SQL_CREATE_PROC = "CREATE PROCEDURE insLog(IN P1 VARCHAR(30))"  
                    + " LANGUAGE JAVA"  
                    + " SPECIFIC insLog"  
                    + " DETERMINISTIC"  
                    + " NO SQL"  
                    + " EXTERNAL NAME \"DbLog::insLog\""  
                    + " PARAMETER STYLE SQL";    


                m_stmt = conn.createStatement();   
                m_stmt.executeUpdate(SQL_CREATE_PROC);   
                m_stmt.close();     
                m_callStmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call PBPUBLIC.insLog(?) }");   
                m_callStmt.setString(1, "Success!!");   
                m_callStmt.execute();    

            }   


            catch (Exception e) {   
                logger.error("Error in logPreAuth method" + e);   
            }   


        }   

    public void insLog(String test)   
    {   
        try {   

            l_stmt = conn.createStatement();   
            l_stmt.execute("Insert into logs values('" + test + "')");   
            l_stmt.close();   
            conn.close();   
        }   
        catch (Exception e) {   

        }   

    }   
    }
```

Comment: The real error is further down in the stacktrace. Post the ENTIRE stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.local.util.common.DbLog

This basically means that `Class.forName("net.local.util.common.DbLog")` has failed with an exception. This can in turn mean that any of the `static` variables or initializer blocks of the class in question threw an unhandled exception. They are namely executed during class loading.

You've two of them in that class:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DbLog.class);   
private static boolean DEBUGGING = logger.isDebugEnabled();
```

Either of them has thus thrown an exception. Its stacktrace is visible further down in your log. Go back reading your logs and check the bottommost exception of the stacktrace. This is the first root cause. It should be self-explaining enough. Perhaps Log4j is missing in the runtime classpath or so.